# If the singular value decomposition $U\Sigma V^T$ has rank $r$ and $Q$ is semi-orthogonal, then $Q\Sigma V^T$ has rank $r$ as well

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, singular-values, unitary-matrices

Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$ and $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with reduced singular value decomposition $U\Sigma V^T$, \begin{align}U&\in\mathbb R^{m\times r},\\\Sigma&\in\mathbb R^{r\times r},\\V&\in\mathbb R^{n\times r}.\end{align} Now let $Q\in\mathbb R^{l\times  r}$ be [semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix), $$QQ^T=I_l\tag1.$$

> Let $B:=Q\Sigma V^T$. How can we conclude that $\operatorname{rank}B=r$?

Clearly, $r=\operatorname{rank}A$.

Comment: If C is an $l \times m$ matrix of rank $m$, then
${\displaystyle \operatorname {rank} (CA)=\operatorname {rank} (A).}$ will this help?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not true.

Let $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\Sigma=V=I_3$.

Then 
$\mathrm{rank}\Sigma=r=3$ and $\mathrm{rank}Q\Sigma V^T=2\neq r$.

Comment: It seems like you're right. Maybe I've missed some assumption, but I think the claim is being made [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.08513.pdf) on page 14 ("This is a valid SVD of ...")